# vb interfaces with linq-to-sql

Tags: .net, linq

I am having trouble with casting and interfaces. Below is the code I am using. What the error says. I dont fully understand what is going on. I thought that if i created a list of items which implement an interface, if i pass another item which also implements the interface then it should work. But it doesn't. Can someone explain why it doesn't and what I should do instead. Thank you very much

The error line has three astrix's to identify it. Again thank you very much

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in DAL.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast
>   object of type
>   'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[BuisnessObjects.Project]'
>   to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[BuisnessObjects.IProject]'

```
Imports BuisnessObjects
Public Class ProjectInfoRepository
    Implements IProjectInfoRepository
             Function GetAllProjects() As List(Of BuisnessObjects.IProject) Implements IProjectInfoRepository.GetAllProjects
        Dim returnList As New List(Of BuisnessObjects.IProject)
        ***returnList.AddRange(From p In DC.ProjectInfos _
                          Select New BuisnessObjects.Project() With {.ProjectID = p.projectID, .ProjectName = p.projectName})***

        Return returnList
    End Function
End Class


Public Class Project
    Implements IProject
    Private _projectName As String
    Property ProjectName() As String Implements IProject.ProjectName
        Get
            Return _projectName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _projectName = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _projectID As Integer
    Property ProjectID() As Integer Implements IProject.ProjectID
        Get
            Return _projectID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _projectID = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class


Public Interface IProject
    Property ProjectName() As String
    Property ProjectID() As Integer
End Interface
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a `.Cast(Of BuisnessObjects.IProject)` to the linq query it should work.

```
Function GetAllProjects() As List(Of BuisnessObjects.IProject) Implements IProjectInfoRepository.GetAllProjects
        Dim returnList As New List(Of BuisnessObjects.IProject)

        returnList.AddRange((From p In DC.ProjectInfos _
                            Select New BuisnessObjects.Project() With {.ProjectID = p.projectID, .ProjectName = p.projectName}).Cast(Of BuisnessObjects.IProject))

        Return returnList
End Function
```

Comment: Seems kind've weird why I have to cast it. Can you explain why please. Also thank you for the help, it worked